# ¿Cómo activar un solo status de dos tipos de ambiente prueba y producción?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada `tbl_biller` para explicarlo más sencillo se va realizar solo con 2 registros:

| id_biller | id_enterprise | biller | ambient | a_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 28 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

Ahora explico que significa cada columna:

- `id_enterprise:` ID de la empresa.
- `biller:` Tipo de comprobante (1 = factura).
- `ambient:` Tipo de producción (1 = pruebas, 2 = producción)
- `a_stactus:` Activar datos para ejecutar en PHP.

Todo registro nuevo siempre va estar por default `0` en `a_status`.

Ambos registros pueden estar en 0, en el `a_status` pero nunca deben estar ambos en `1` solo uno de los dos registros puede tener `1`.

Para saber que registro se va realizar estos cambios la condición `WHERE` es la siguiente:

```
WHERE id_biller=1 AND id_enterprise=28 AND biller=1
```

Ahora como se debe preparar el `UPDATE` que cumpla la siguiente condición:

- Se puede desactivar ambos registros `a_status` con el valor `0`
- Pero si se activa uno con el valor de 1, se debe verificar que el otro este en `0` en caso de tener `1` actualizar en `0` y dejar en uno el que se intenta activar, para saber cuál es, se verifica con la condición pasada en el `WHERE` `id_biller`.

Entonces, ¿cómo debería quedar?

---

Normalmente mi `UPDATE` es simple y me gustaría que funcione aquellas condiciones sin tantos `UPDATE` individuales.

```
UPDATE tbl_biller
SET a_status = 1
WHERE id_biller=1 AND id_enterprise=28 AND biller=1
```

Comment: Como tienes tu update actual?

Comment: @Pipe Pregunta actualizada, el `UPDATE` disponible es muy simple amigo

Comment: Con `SET a_estatus = if(id_biller=1,1,0) WHERE id_enterprise=28 and biller=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo que, cada vez que quieras cambiar de un estado a otro, utilices estas tres consultas en bloque, que siempre puedes incluir en un procedimiento almacenado:

```
UPDATE tbl_biller
  SET a_status=2
  WHERE id_enterprise=28
  AND biller=1
  AND a_status=1;
UPDATE tbl_biller JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id_biller) id_biller
      FROM tbl_biller
      WHERE id_enterprise=28
      AND biller=1
      AND a_status=0
  ) c1 USING(id_biller)
  SET a_status=1;
UPDATE tbl_biller
  SET a_status=0
  WHERE a_status=2;
```

Aporto el dataset para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_biller(
  id_biller int,
  id_enterprise int,
  biller int,
  ambient int,
  a_status int
  );
INSERT INTO tbl_biller
  (id_biller, id_enterprise, biller, ambient, a_status) VALUES
  (1,28,1,1,0),
  (2,28,1,2,0);
```

Espero que te resulte útil, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Pongo a 2 lo que está a 1 para poder poner a 1 el último que esté en 0 y, después, poner a 0 lo que temporalmente dejé en 2. Fíjate en que sirve incluso si tienes más de dos opciones.

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo una curiosidad amigo, es que observó que un `a_status` le realizas un `SET` de  `2`

Comment: Te amplío la respuesta para responder a tu comentario

Comment: No pasa nada si le quito `AND a_status` de la condición `WHERE` ya que los datos que envío para ejecutar está consulta en condición `WHERE` solo es el `id_biller, id_enterprise, biller` o se tiene que dejar esos valores en `a_status` por `DEFAULT`

Comment: Que datos deben quedar por `DEFAULT` y que datos se deben pasar por `PHP` para ejecutar el `UPDATE` normalmente tenía así: `$stmt->bind_param('iiii', $id_biller, $id_enterprise, $biller, $set_status); pero yo solo enviaba un solo valor en la variable `$set_status` que era `1` o `0` aquí realizando pruebas no logro entender como vincular `PHP` con su procedimiento mencionado https://paiza.io/projects/fJBYFe-jL2qJEgS1OD7aKg?language=mysql

Comment: Para que funcione como esperas, no puedes enviar `id_biller`. Ten en cuenta que, en unos casos es uno y, en otros, el otro :)

Comment: Tendría que enviar los datos por Ajax tipo array, tendría que enviar más de dos datos ya veo que opción es más fácil su respuesta o la otra

Answer (score 1):

Yo pensaría en hacer multiples consultas.

Como no compartes código PHP no se que librería estás usando ni como tienes estructurado el código, te dejo aquí el "algoritmo" que yo usaría.
Me inventé una función ficticia `ConsultarBaseDeDatos` que lo que hace es ejecutar las consultas a la BD, pero en la realidad tu usarias `mysqli_query` o cualquier ORM que tengas en tu proyecto.

Algo como:

```
//Supongo que estas variables las obtienes de algún lado para saber cual es el registro que quieres activar, de momento yo las defino directamente
$id_biller=1 
$id_enterprise=28
$biller=1

//Cuentas cuantos registros hay en la base de datos que tengan un id_biller distinto y que estén activos
$resultado = ConsultarBaseDeDatos("COUNT * FROM tbl_biller WHERE id_biller!=$id_biller AND id_enterprise=$id_enterpries AND biller=$biller AND a_status=1");

if($resultado>0) {
   //Existe un registro activo con id_biller distinto, por lo tanto debe 
desactivarse
   ConsultarBaseDeDatos("UPDATE tbl_biller
SET a_status=0 WHERE id_biller!=$id_biller AND id_enterprise=$id_enterpries AND biller=$biller AND a_status=1");
}

//Ya sabiendo que no hay ningún registro activo, activas el que quieres
ConsultarBaseDeDatos("UPDATE tbl_biller
SET a_status=1 WHERE id_biller=$id_biller AND id_enterprise=$id_enterpries AND biller=$biller");
```

> NOTA: Recuerda que la concatenación de parametros en el string está totalmente desaconsejado, pues podrías quedar expuesto a inyección SQL, solo lo hago para simplificar el ejercicio, pero debes usar prepared statements.